# Dealing with Many Different SQL Queries in PHP

Tags: php, sql, design-patterns

I have a web application that uses a few dozen different queries to display various different results from the web.  These queries are all relatively unique, use different tables and are already combined as much as they can be.  I can't change the schema so my SQL is set in stone.

The current set up I am using is more or less a big function libraries where each function takes a common connection to the database, performs the query defined in the function and then echos the data out in whatever way it needs to be.  I'm considering OOP to make things less redundant but I'm struggling to see how I can deal with SQL queries.  I have almost 2000 lines of pure SQL polluting my code.  It works, but it really looks like a maintenance nightmare to me.

What is a good practice for storing these queries?

Just to clarify, I'm talking about variables that hold my SQL strings.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=x"
```

Only with too many to reasonably keep track of.

Comment: Honestly that's probably the best solution.  The only issue being I don't really have enough control of the database to implement that solution.

Comment: IMHO this question is too non-specific to give a reasonable answer to. It sounds like the number of queries could probably be reduced with some well placed `JOIN`s (a few dozen queries per page load is, in general, a *lot*) although it depends on your use case and we'd need to see some code. Likewise some prepared statements might help, but that also depends on your use case and we'd need to see some code. Essentially what I'm saying is "it depends on your use case and we'd need to see some code".

Comment: I usually use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and describe my query in code.  I've never used any PHP ORM frameworks though.

Comment: @DaveRandom Unfortunately "Posting Code" means posting SQL queries, and given the nature of my problem, that would probably send this question in the opposite direction and make it way to specific, i.e. 'Pls fix my terrible SQL'.  The prepared statements route seems like a potentially good option though.  The backend is MSSQL Server so it's definitely possible.

Comment: In the Java/C# world the winner would be MyBatis (iBatis). This seems to be the only serious clone seems to be http://www.pradosoft.com/demos/sqlmap/ .